# Aurelia validation is not showing up

Tags: javascript, aurelia

javascript:

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {Validation} from 'aurelia-validation';

@inject(Validation)
export class CreateExecutedAgreement {
    constructor(validation) {
        this.agreementType = "";
        this.counterparty = "";
        this.validation = validation.on(this)
        .ensure('agreementType')
            .isNotEmpty()
        .ensure('counterparty')
            .isNotEmpty();
    }
}
```

html:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="counterparty">Counterparty</label>
    <select value.bind="counterparty" id="counterparty" class="form-control">
        <option value=""><- Select -></option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I can see that the validation is doing something in the page because I see the

```
<p class="help-block aurelia-validation-message"></p>
```

appended after the label but when I focus and blur the textbox I am not seeing any messages, css changes etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check your css are loaded properly? is it possible bootstrap.css was not loaded correctly?

Comment: @EliranMalka No, bootstrap is definitely loaded ok. Is there any other css that I need to load? This isn't just an issue of css. None of the messages are showing up (when I inspect the html source - there are no messages in the help-blocks) event after I have focused/blurred the select.

Answer (score 0):

```
<template>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="counterparty">Counterparty</label>
        <select value.bind="counterparty" id="counterparty" class="form control" validate.bind="validation">
            <option value=""> <- Select -> </option>
            <option>test value</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</template>
```

or this

```
<template>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="counterparty">Counterparty</label>
        <select value.bind="counterparty" id="counterparty" class="form-control" validate.bind="validation">
            <option></option>
            <option>test value</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add validate property to select element**

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label>Counterparty</label>
      <select value.bind="counterparty" id="counterparty" class="form-control" validate="counterparty">
             <option value=""><- Select -></option>
      </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Added validate keyword with value.bind

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="counterparty">Counterparty</label>
    <select value.bind="counterparty & validate" id="counterparty" class="form-control">
        <option value=""><- Select -></option>
    </select>
</div>
```